# a specific domain cannot be loaded in a webview

Tags: xcode, react-native, webview

I have to load an https URL in a webview but I get an error `NSURLErrorDomain: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. (-1200: NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed)`

I added the domain in the .plist:

[image: NSExceptionDomains]

but still the same error...

When I load the URL in the Simulator's Safari I can load the page without error.

It doesn't work with this specific domain but the webview works with for example https://www.google.com

Do you have some ideas to fix this problem ?

Thx

Comment: try this: remove all except `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` under `NSAppTransportSecurity` and run your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still the same problem, I checked the simulator logs and nothing... why can I load the url with simulator's Safari but not in the webview...

Comment: I tried to fetch the url in my code and same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain that I want to call is using a TLS v1.0 and Apple wants at least a TLS v1.1.

So I added "App Transport Security Settings" > "Exception Domains" > "my.domain.com" >  `NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion: "TLSv1.0"`